# What is the best way to implement the following type of paradigm?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, python-3.x

I have the following piece of code. Line 1 is a container (for simplicity, one can think of it as a list of elements e1, e2, ..., en). Now there is a function `function_fun` which takes as input an element `ei` and returns a list of elements. So finally we need to recursively keep processing elements from `container` and apply `function_fun` to get new elements such that the `container` satisfies `some_property`. Is this a general paradigm, and is there any faster way to do this?

```
   1. container = [e1, e2, ..., en]
   2. while (!some_property(container))
   3.    temp_container = []
   4.    for e in container
   5.       ttemp_container = function_fun(e)
   5.       temp_container = temp_container + ttemp_container
   6.    container = temp_container
   7.    return container
```

If someone wants a concrete example of this, then let's say we want to generate all binary strings of length `n`. Here is how we will implement it here:

```
   1. container = ["0","1"]
   2. while (len(container[0])!=n)
   3.    temp_container = []
   4.    for e in container
   5.       ttemp_container = [e+"0", e+"1"]
   5.       temp_container = temp_container + ttemp_container
   6.    container = temp_container
   7.    return container
```

Comment: In maths it may be called a *transitive closure*